# Some products not displaying after moving servers

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have successfully moved a magento store from one server to another and everything works as expected. Most of the products are displaying when i browse through the store with the exception of some products where only the top header template shows with the bottom completely blank.

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here are some of the tips for debugging

1. Disable the cache
2. Re-index the data (System > Index Management)
3. Enable the log (System > Advanced > Developers ..)
4. Try to reload the page
5. check for log files under var/log/*.log

Hope this helps you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When a substantial chunk of the page is missing (as you say, everything after the header), the best first guess is that an exception is being thrown on the page. Check the source of the page first of all (in case your errors are being printed). If they are not, make sure that logging is enabled for your store and check the error logs to see what exception you are throwing.

Fix that and all should be well. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe